# We can see the changes when we access it using Preview store but not live in shopify

Tags: shopify

I am new to Shopify and trying to make the changes in the code. When I click on **Preview store** button after making changes in the theme, it does get reflected in the browser but when I access it in the other browser / incognito **without Preview store**, the changes doesn't get reflected.

Note : I don't have access other than Themes in admin

Comment: It's not really possible to know what is happening with that much information. Are you editing the live theme, if you are previewing a theme maybe you have made changes to an offline theme and have not published the theme?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue as it needs to get published. I am new to Shopify, that's why didn't know it and moreover I didn't have the other permissions too.